# How can I make sure my content_script.js DOM manipulations don't get overwritten by current html page

Tags: google-chrome, scripting

I've created a Chome content_script extension and i'm trying to add some elements to a Twitter page.

I've been able to add my elements no problem into the page, but the elements I added don't stay on the page for long, I think Twitter is running some requests and updating the html all the time so it removes my elements.

How would I be able to keep my elements on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a solution to my question heh I just needed to check for elements there were always being refreshed and just update the DOM element when the elements changed.